# \fcolorbox in \begin{equation}

Tags: equations, colorbox

Good evening

I do not understand why Overleaf tells me that there is an error in this code

`\begin{equation}\fcolorbox{black}{gray!30}{$\color{blue}{\displaystyle{\lim_{n\longrightarrow+\infty}\dfrac{n!}{\Tonde{\dfrac{n}{e}}^n\sqrt{2n\pi}}=1}}$} \end{equation}`

Where \Tonde{} means `\left(...\right)`

Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would be better for all of us if you can provide a complete but minimal example regarding the code you have as well as the error message. Nonetheless, I will assume you have `\usepackage{tcolorbox}` added. Here is a quick fix that might help out: place a newline after `\begin{equation}` (i.e., press Enter only once).

Comment: No. I do not have `\usepackage{tcolorbox}`. Thank you

Comment: My main question is: Does `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` support an `\fcolorbox{}{}{}`?

Comment: Yes, it does. I have tested it on my machine. Furthermore, it will not work in the `standalone` document class. Also, you need the `amsmath` package loaded too.

Comment: For future reference, please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228 and follow the tips in your next question.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\Tonde}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \fcolorbox{black}
    {gray!30}
    {
        $\color{blue}
            \displaystyle{
                \lim_{n\longrightarrow+\infty}
                \dfrac{n!}{\Tonde{\dfrac{n}{e}}^n\sqrt{2n\pi}}=1
            }
        $
    }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need `tcolorbox` here... only `xcolor`. Also, you have some spurious spaces in your definition, including some unnecessary bracing.

Comment: Thanx. Unfortunately, Overleaf keeps giving me error. Another question: What is the difference between `\usepackage{amsmath}`  and `\usepackage{amsmath,pict2e}`? However I use `\usepackage{stix}`. Does `\usepackage{stix}` make error for `\fcolorbox{}{}{}`? Thanx again.

Comment: @Puck please fix your question so that it has an example document that shows the problem, don't make people guess what you have done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I get no error. On the other hand, you can improve the display, see the second coding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\Tonde}[1]{\left(#1\right)}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\fcolorbox{black}{gray!30}{$\color{blue}{\displaystyle{\lim_{n\longrightarrow+\infty}\dfrac{n!}{\Tonde{\dfrac{n}{e}}^n\sqrt{2n\pi}}=1}}$} \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\fcolorbox{black}{gray!30}{%
  $\color{blue}\displaystyle
  \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\dfrac{n!}{\left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^{\!n\mathstrut}\sqrt{2n\pi}}=1
  $}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Points to note

1. `\color{<color spec>}` takes no second argument; nor does `\displaystyle`.
2. The `\!` in the exponent moves it a bit nearer to the big parenthesis; the `\mathstrut` moves the denominator a bit farther from the main fraction line.
3. `\longrightarrow` is definitely too long.

Comment: Thank you so much. At the end I decided to completely change my tex-code so: `\hfsetfillcolor{gray!30}
\hfsetbordercolor{red}
\begin{equation}\label{StirlingLim}
\tikzmarkin[disable rounded corners=true]{b}(0.25,-1.25)(-0.25,0.8)\color{blue}{\Stirling}\tikzmarkend{b}
\end{equation}`. I like this version with tikz. For now my main goal is to learn tikz. Thank you again